# Is it possible to add inline javascript/css to a magento block?

Tags: javascript, css, magento, block, inline

I want to add a self contained block to magento.  I've successfully added a block of code to the template/pages folder and am able to see the output in my cms page.

Now I want to add some css and javascript for that output but it seems like Magento only supports specifying a javascript file or css file.  Instead I would like to add the css/javascript inline, is this possible?

In the zend framework I would be able to use headscript()->startCapture() etc.. but I'm not sure how to access this from magento.  Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a block to the header using one of the layout files.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head"><!-- this means you are adding to the head block -->
        <block type="core/template" name="custom_styles" as="custom_styles" template="custom/styles.phtml" /><!-- this is a general block with a custom template -->
    </reference>
</default>
```

and in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/custom/styles.phtml` add this:

```
<style>
/* your styles here*/
</style>
```

You can even add some custom js in the same file. After the styles above add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //your js here
</script>
```

Clear the cache and give it a try.

Comment: But wouldn't this mean having the code in one file and the css and javascript in another file, whilst also needing to add a reference to the "style" file into a layout file?  I really just want to have one file, with everything in it, so that if required, I can just delete that one file without needing to do anything else.  The "inline" part of my question was the import part, but maybe I have misunderstood your answer?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your question. You can add your style and js directly in the template file you are using to render your block. You will need to create at least 2 files anyway. One for the block class and one for the template. This is how magento makes the 'separation of concerns'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: Thanks, I figured out I could just add the css and js straight into my template file.  Unfortunately I also figured out that to get what I want isn't going to be quick and easy and I need to build a more involved Plugin.  Though your input was very helpful and solved the original problem.  So Thanks.